# freezing the "tensorflow object detection api pet detector" graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I've followed the pet detector tutorial, i have exported the model using "export_inference_graph.py".

However when I try to freeze the graph using the provided "freeze_graph.py" but now sure what --output_node_names to use.

Does anyone know which I should use, or more importantly how I find out what to use for when I train my own model.

Answer (score 0):

To find what to use for output_node_names, just checkout the graph.pbtxt file. In this case it was Softmax

Answer (score 0):

The output of export_inference_graph.py should currently already be a frozen graph, so it would be redundant to try to freeze it again.

For the input and output node names of the resulting frozen graph, check out the [jupyter notebook](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb) that we provide.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I have ran through the provided notepad with my frozen graph but I am currently getting this error:
KeyError: "The name 'image_tensor:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'image_tensor', does not exist in the graph."

Comment: a list of all the op names i exported from detection_graph.get_operations()  https://pastebin.com/3XvMZrLE

Comment: I'm assuming because I have no similar operations something has gone seriously wrong somewherel. I followed the tutorial, using my own images and labelImg to annotate those.

Comment: Okay, so I've done the whole process end to end with my images resized to 20% the original size and it's gone way better, my eval ran smoothly. I used the ssd_inception_v2 feature extractor this time.

This time when I look inside my graph.pbtxt I'm not sure which node I should use to export? Softmax isn't there, is there a different output node for ssd_inception_v2 ?

I guess a better question is how do I know which node to select from graph.pbtxt. I think it's the only thing missing from the tutorials.